# NSKeyedArchiver fails to archive an NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

What I'm trying to do is simply:

```
NSArray *dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *d = [dirs[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.archive"];
BOOL r = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:d toFile:d];
NSLog(@"%d", r);
```

And the code fails every time (meaning log shows 0, and no file is created in the corresponding file path).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure you can create that file (permissions, existence, etc.)? Does `archivedDataWithRootObject:` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

I think you mean `NSDocumentsDirectory`, not `NSDocumentationDirectory`. Try logging `d` as well as `r` to see what path you're trying to write to. As is I think you'll get `(null)`.